# modify a character variable by matching a mapping structure in r

Tags: r, match

I need to modify a character variable based on a mapping data frame embedding diagonal order numbers.

Here is how my three matrices look like.

```
# for Group 1
Group.1 <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
diag <- rep("Free",length(Group.1)+1)
offdiag <- rep("0.0", (length(Group.1)+1)*length(Group.1)/2 )
m1 <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(diag), nrow = length(diag))
m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- offdiag
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- t(m1)[upper.tri(t(m1))]
diag(m1) <- diag
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- NA

> m1
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  
[1,] "Free" NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
[2,] "0.0"  "Free" NA     NA     NA     NA    
[3,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" NA     NA     NA    
[4,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" NA     NA    
[5,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free" NA    
[6,] "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "0.0"  "Free"

inds.1 <- which(na.omit(c(t(m1))) == 'Free')[-1] - 1
> inds.1
[1]  2  5  9 14 20
```

`inds.1`, `inds.2`, and `inds.3` store the order number of the `Free` for each matrix. Note that the first `Free`s order is `0`. That is why the second `Free` has an order number of `2` instead of `3`. The third `Free` has an order number of `5` and so on.

```
# for Group 2
Group.2 <- c(11,13,15)
diag <- rep("Free",length(Group.2)+1)
offdiag <- rep("0.0", (length(Group.2)+1)*length(Group.2)/2 )
m2 <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(diag), nrow = length(diag))
m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- offdiag
m2[upper.tri(m2)] <- t(m2)[upper.tri(t(m2))]
diag(m2) <- diag
m2[upper.tri(m2)] <- NA

inds.2 <- which(na.omit(c(t(m2))) == 'Free')[-1] - 1
> inds.2
[1] 2 5 9

# for Group 3
Group.3 <- c(12,13,14)
diag <- rep("Free",length(Group.3)+1)
offdiag <- rep("0.0", (length(Group.3)+1)*length(Group.3)/2 )
m3 <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(diag), nrow = length(diag))
m3[lower.tri(m3)] <- offdiag
m3[upper.tri(m3)] <- t(m3)[upper.tri(t(m3))]
diag(m3) <- diag
m3[upper.tri(m3)] <- NA

inds.3 <- which(na.omit(c(t(m3))) == 'Free')[-1] - 1
> inds.3
[1] 2 5 9

# create grouping map
map.1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Items=Group.1, Group.1 = 1))
map.2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Items=Group.2, Group.2 = 1))
map.3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Items=Group.3, Group.3 = 1))

group.map.12 <- merge(map.1, map.2, by="Items", all = TRUE)
group.map.all <- merge(group.map.12, map.3, by="Items", all = TRUE)
group.map.all[is.na(group.map.all)] <- 0

> group.map.all
  Items Group.1 Group.2 Group.3
1    11       1       1       0
2    12       1       0       1
3    13       1       1       1
4    14       1       0       1
5    15       1       1       0
```

This map tells which item is in which group.

Based on this information I was able to create an output but I need some modification on this.:

```
output <- c("Equal = (G1, 11, Covariance[X]), (G2, 11, Covariance[X]);",                         
"Equal = (G1, 12, Covariance[X]), (G3, 12, Covariance[X]);",                         
"Equal = (G1, 13, Covariance[X]), (G2, 13, Covariance[X]), (G3, 13, Covariance[X]);",
"Equal = (G1, 14, Covariance[X]), (G3, 14, Covariance[X]);",                         
"Equal = (G1, 15, Covariance[X]), (G2, 15, Covariance[X]);") 

> output
[1] "Equal = (G1, 11, Covariance[X]), (G2, 11, Covariance[X]);"                         
[2] "Equal = (G1, 12, Covariance[X]), (G3, 12, Covariance[X]);"                         
[3] "Equal = (G1, 13, Covariance[X]), (G2, 13, Covariance[X]), (G3, 13, Covariance[X]);"
[4] "Equal = (G1, 14, Covariance[X]), (G3, 14, Covariance[X]);"                         
[5] "Equal = (G1, 15, Covariance[X]), (G2, 15, Covariance[X]);"
```

Two things to modify in this output.

1. remove numbers with the commas (so `11,` `12,` etc.. need to be removed.
2. For each line in the output, the `[X]` needs to be edited to indicate the matching matrix order numbers. For example, from the mapping, `Item=12` is in `G1` and `G3` and in Group 1, the matrix order number is `5` from `inds.1` object. In group 2, the matrix order number is `2` from `inds.1` object for this `Item=12`. I need to embed those numbers in `[X}`.

The desired output would be:

```
Equal=(G1,Covariance[2]),(G2,Covariance[2]);
Equal=(G1,Covariance[5]),(G2,Covariance[2]);
Equal=(G1,Covariance[9]),(G2,Covariance[5]),(G3,Covariance[5]);
Equal=(G1,Covariance[14]),(G3,Covariance[9]);
Equal=(G1,Covariance[20]),(G2,Covariance[9]);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to create the 'output' first and then modify or should that be directly from 'group.map.all'?

Comment: @akrun Here is the full version of the story and I showed How I ended up here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295192/write-out-a-statement-using-element-orders-from-matrices-for-matching-items-in-r

Comment: The logic for the second/third set of Covariance replacement number is not clear to me

Comment: an example let's look at the third row of the output. that belongs to `item=13`. From the `inds` objects, which tells the item order in the matrix, this item is seen in all three groups. the first group has the `item=13` order number `9`, the second group has the `item=13` order number `5` and the third group has the order number `5` in the individual matrices. This tries to find the order numbers for each item from different matrices and put them in one line. hope this is a little more clear.

Comment: what is the logic for the 5 value in 'item=13'

Comment: There are `Free` values in the matrices. The order of the first `Free` is `0`. Then I have `0.0` in the matrix, the order number is `1`, then I have second `Free` value, the order is assigned `2`, then I have `0.0` and another `0.0` in the matrix, the orders are assigned `3`, and `4`, subsequently. Then I came to the third `Free` value, now I need to assign `5` for that.   This line assigns those order numbers for the `Free` values `inds.1 <- which(na.omit(c(t(m1))) == 'Free')[-1] - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps -

1. Loop `across` the 'Group' columns, `replace` the binary to logical converted with the corresponding values of 'inds' objects
2. Reshape to long format -`pivot_longer`
3. Remove the rows where the 'value' column is 0 -`filter`
4. Remove the substring from 'name' column -`str_remove`
5. Create a new formatted column from 'name', 'value' - `sprintf`
6. Group by 'Items', `paste` the 'new' column -`str_c`
7. Extract the column as a vector -`pull`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
group.map.all %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('Group'),
     ~ replace(., as.logical(.), 
        get(str_replace(cur_column(), "Group", "inds"))))) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -Items) %>%
    filter(value != 0) %>% 
    mutate(name = str_remove(name, "[a-z.]+")) %>%
    summarise(Items, new = sprintf('(%s,Covariance[%d])', name, value)) %>%  
    group_by(Items) %>% 
    summarise(new = str_c('Equal=',str_c(new, collapse=","), ";")) %>%
    pull(new)
```

-output

```
[1] "Equal=(G1,Covariance[2]),(G2,Covariance[2]);"  
[2] "Equal=(G1,Covariance[5]),(G3,Covariance[2]);"                   
[3] "Equal=(G1,Covariance[9]),(G2,Covariance[5]),(G3,Covariance[5]);"
[4] "Equal=(G1,Covariance[14]),(G3,Covariance[9]);"                  
[5] "Equal=(G1,Covariance[20]),(G2,Covariance[9]);"
```

Comment: Hi @akrun thanks for your response. `a)` I think I am using the old dplyr version since I had an error for the `across()` function. This is what the error looks like. `Error in across(starts_with("Group"), ~replace(., as.logical(.), get(str_replace(cur_column(),  : 
  could not find function "across"`.  You previously suggested using `filter_at` instead of `across`? `b)` Another thing to remove is `11,12,13,14,15` at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: @amisos55 The `b)` is just a column.  You can extract `new` as `%>% pull(new)`.  Regarding the `a)` can you just update your dplyr version?  I used `cur_column()` etc which won't work with your old version

Comment: @amisos55 I could write the code replacement for across, but I can't test it because my new version may result in some errors when I use old code

Comment: I can test on my end now if you suggest a replacement. My server does not currently let me update dplyr. that is the issue actually.

Comment: in the output I need the first `Equal`  for each row. so I need `Equal=(G1,Covariance[2]),(G2,Covariance[2]);` instead of `Equal=(G1,Covariance[2]),Equal=(G2,Covariance[2]); ` . Could you also edit that please? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this `Equal =` part by  `output$new <- gsub(", Equal =", ",", output$new)`.

Comment: @amisos55 i updated.  In the sprintf, remove the 'Equal=', and then at the last str_c, add the Equal=

Comment: can you also provide a line for the old `dplyr` ? I can test on my end.

Comment: @amisos55 with your old package, i am not sure which all functions will work i.e. I used `pivot_longer`, `cur_column()`, `across` etc.

Comment: @amisos55 Try`group.map.all %>%
            mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Group')),
             ~ replace(., as.logical(.), 
                get(str_replace(deparse(substitute(.)), "Group", "inds"))))) %>% 
            gather(name, value, -Items) %>%
            filter(value != 0) %>% 
            mutate(name = str_remove(name, "[a-z.]+")) %>%
            summarise(Items, new = sprintf('(%s,Covariance[%d])', name, value)) %>%  
            group_by(Items) %>% 
            summarise(new = str_c('Equal=',str_c(new, collapse=","), ";")) %>%
            pull(new)` (not tested)

Comment: It gives this warning after I run `mutate_at()` part `Warning messages:
1: In x[list] <- values :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In x[list] <- values :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` . It is ok, I do not want to take too much of your time. I will try to figure out the rest. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @amisos55 I already told you that I cannot test it on my system

Comment: @amisos55 the `deparse/substitute` may not work in certain versions.  I don't know which version you use and it is a bit difficult to help when you can't update your package

Comment: I fixed the update issue. Thanks a lot again!